# How i return data in Laravel from Vue.js Axios

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a textarea and I try to submit data with axios and vue to laravel but it doesn't work.I try to take the data and put ucfirst then return it.

```
new Vue({
el:'#root',
data:{

  areamodel: ''
},

methods:{
 insert:function(){
     axios.post('/vue').then(response => this.areamodel = response.data);
   }

}

});
```

and

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
       public function vue(Request $request)
    {
$abc = ucfirst($request->input('areamodel'));

return $abc;


    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error displayed?

Comment: just blank no error when i go to vue dev tools it just the areamodel: ""

Comment: try ```console.log(response.data);```

Comment: in dev tool now it shows areamodel:undefined

Comment: I have posted a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the instance of vue is not available inside the axios.

```
new Vue({
el:'#root',
data:{
  areamodel: ''
},

methods:{
 insert:function(){
     let vueInstance = this; //This line is important

     axios.post('/vue', {areamodel: vueInstance.areamodel}).then(
       function(response){
         vueInstance.areamodel = response.data.areamodel;
       }
     ).catch(function(error){ console.log(error.message); });
   }
}

});
```

And server side

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
   public function vue(Request $request)
   {
     $abc = ucfirst($request->input('areamodel'));

     return response()->json(['areamodel' => $abc]);

   }
}
```

Comment: same, i think it has something in laravel

Comment: i put this return ['areamodel']; and now it work but it just areamodel back, i need the output of the areamodel

Comment: it returns [object Object]

Comment: Did you replace ```response.data``` with ```response.data.areamodel```

Comment: it returns [object Object] right? So in console you can expand the object in network tab in dev tools. Can you try it and confirm if response is correct?

Comment: when i put response.data.areamodel  it reponse is blank in vue dev tools the areamodel is blank and no errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151813/discussion-between-adrian-klark-and-curious-coder).